# there infinitely many postive integer $n$ such $\sigma(n)$ are square

Tags: number-theory

show that: there infinitely many postive integer $n$ such $\sigma(n)$ are square

where $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of divisors function

maybe this is old question,and I can't found it mathstack,and I have only find this question:[On $\phi(n) \sigma(n)$ being a square.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983605/on-phin-sigman-being-a-square/2989924#2989924)

Comment: For additional context : if $n = \prod p_i^{a_i}$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes and $a_i>0$, then $\sigma(n) = \prod \frac{p_i^{a_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}$ is a formula for the sum-of-divisors function. One may try to use this : in particular, it may be useful to understand when each term $ \frac{p_i^{a_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}$ is a perfect square.

Comment: There are indications [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289856/when-is-the-sum-of-divisors-a-perfect-square) that this is only a conjecture. It would be true [if there were infinitely many Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_conjectures#Lenstra%E2%80%93Pomerance%E2%80%93Wagstaff_conjecture), in which case multiplying any two of them greater than 3, along with 3 itself, would qualify.

Comment: Another sufficient condition is that there are infinite many primes of the form $2^a\cdot 3^b-1$. Depending on the parities of $a,b$ , we can chose $30p,34p,22p,11p$ , if $p>34$ is the prime of the form $2^a\cdot 3^b-1$.

Comment: If there are infinite many primes $p$ , such that both $2p-1$ and $8p-1$ are prime, then there are infinite many cases since $(2p-1)(8p-1)$ does the job. And of course we can construct tons of such families by replacing $2$ and $8$ by other numbers multiplying to a perfect square. The Schinzel hypothesis hence also implies infinite many cases.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, the OEIS link http://oeis.org/A006532 now contains a comment that there *are* infinitely many $n$ such that $\sigma(n)$ is a square, with a link to.a *Math Monthly* paper from 2012 by Beukers et. al., "Power Values of Divisor Sums." (I'll update my comment at the link you gave, which predates the update to the OEIS entry, albeit not the *Math Monthly* paper.)

Comment: Link to Barry's reference: https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.119.05.373